# using single text box to enter value in other box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to create text box which is used to enter value in other 4 text box one by one

i had tryed the below code but it copy's only to one text box...

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function copy_data(val){
    var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
    document.getElementById("copy_to").value=a
    }


    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_from" onKeyUp="copy_data(this)"/>


    <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_to" disabled/>


    <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_to" disabled/>


    <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_to" disabled/>


    <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_to" disabled/>

        enter code here

    <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_to" disabled/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: HTML ID attributes are supposed to be 100% unique. Use a class if you have to repeat something like that

Comment: Also, you could eliminate a whole line of your JS function. You send  `this` into the function, so grabbing the ID is redundant. `document.getElementById("copy_to").value=val.value;` is the exact same

Comment: You cannot use Repeated Same ID for Multiple Elements. It should be Unique. or You can use alternate for ID is CLASS Attribute for Elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Hit Enter Key to copy value):
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTHB/)

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="copy_from" onKeyUp="copy_data(this,event)"/>


<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>


<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>


<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>


<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>

enter code here

<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>

<script>
    var count = 0;
    function copy_data(val, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (count <= 4) {
                var a = document.getElementsByClassName('copy_to')[count];
                a.value = val.value;
                val.value = '';
                count++;
            }
        }
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Cn6Rb/

`Id` are unique do this. i.e. use `class` attribute instead

*API: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Hope this fits your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#copy_from').keyup(function(){

        $('.copy_to').val($(this).val());

    });

});
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="copy_from" />
<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>
<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>
<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>
<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>enter code here
<input type="text" name="a" class="copy_to" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note Id should be unique, use different strategy

**Using Jquery**

javascript code

```
            function copy_data(val){
                  $('.myKlass').val(val.value);  
            }
```

html code

```
    <input type="text" class="myKlass" name ="a" id="copy_to1" disabled/>
    <input type="text" class="myKlass" name ="a" id="copy_to2" disabled/>
    <input type="text" class="myKlass" name ="a" id="copy_to3" disabled/>
```

**Using javascript**

```
    function copy_data(val){
         var elem_list = document.getElementsByName('a');
         for(var i = 1; i < elem_list.length;i++){
             elem_list.item(i).value = val.value;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, class is not the best attribute to do that, as it is supposed to serve as a way to apply styles rather than identifying dom elements. You could use the html5 "data-*" attributes to have a cleaner HTML code, like this:

```
<input type="text" name ="a" data-role="source"/>
<div data-role="destination">
    <input type="text" disabled/>
    <input type="text" disabled/>
    <input type="text" disabled/>
    <input type="text" disabled/>
    <input type="text" disabled/>
</div>
```

This way, you only need two "data-role" polluting your html. The "data-role" attribute is pretty common in jQuery (mainly due Twitter Bootstrap widgets).

Then, you only need this:

```
$("[data-role=source]").on("keyup", function(){
    var that = this;
    $($("[data-role=destination]").children()).each(function(index, item) {
        item.value = that.value;
    });
});
```